# Code sharing between GCC and NVCC

Tags: c++, gcc, cuda

Given some project that is to have an optional CUDA build, how would one share code between the two project variants, such that code reuse is maximised?

For example, in a project where a CUDA build is guaranteed, one can share code between the CPU and GPU portions of the project as follows:-

```
//shared_functions.h
float computeEta(float lambda, int t);

//shared_functions.cu
__host__ __device__ 
float computeEtaDevice(float lambda, int t){
    return (1.0/(lambda*(float)t));
}

float computeEta(float lambda, int t){
    return computeEtaDevice(lambda, t);
}

//test.cpp
#include "shared_functions.h"
...
computeEta(lambda, t);
```

However, it is not clear how this can be achieved in the absence of CUDA at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after some experimentation, it appears that something similar to this does the trick(example written in browser):-

```
//shared.h
#if defined(__CUDACC__) && defined(__CUDA_ARCH__)
    #define __SHARED_CODE__ __device__
#else
    #define __SHARED_CODE__ 
#endif

__SHARED_CODE__
inline float func1(float a, float b){
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to give an answer in that direction when you provided yours. Let me add the following: The standard way in many libraries is to define a macro like `#define CUDA_HOST_DEVICE __host__ __device__` if compiled with `nvcc` and an empty define if compiled with a host compiler.

Comment: @havogt Great idea. Thanks. Updated answer to reflect it.